# Parse massive XML from Google Maps API origins and destinations

Tags: excel, xml, vba, xml-parsing

This question is partly related to [Get Google Maps XML data, parse it and input to Excel cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56810220/). In previous question solution was to loop through links and input values for each one. I have figured out that it is possible to call for multiple origins and destinations and get everything in XML file from Google Maps. Now this is one huge XML to get data out. I need to get duration like `1 hour 30 mins` and distance like `103 km` out for each one. How is this possible?

Also why there is 25 XML responses when I have only 5 different variants?

Here is my VBA:

```vb
Sub GetMyValuesGoogleAPI()
    Dim URL As String
    Dim originsParam As String
    Dim destinationsParam As String
    Dim APIkey As Range, TravelMode As Range

    Dim xmlDoc As DOMDocument30

    Dim origins(0 To 4) As String
    Dim destinations(0 To 4) As String

    Dim n As Integer

    n = FreeFile()
    Open Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\" & "test.txt" For Output As #n

    origins(0) = "London, UK"
    origins(1) = "Manchester, UK"
    origins(2) = "Liverpool, UK"
    origins(3) = "Bristol, UK"
    origins(4) = "Bath, UK"

    destinations(0) = "Cambridge, UK"
    destinations(1) = "Leeds, UK"
    destinations(2) = "Cambridge, UK"
    destinations(3) = "Norwich, UK"
    destinations(4) = "Brighton, UK"

    Set APIkey = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Other Data").Range("CE1")
    Set TravelMode = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Other Data").Range("BY3")
    Set xmlDoc = New DOMDocument30

    originsParam = Join(origins, "|")
    destinationsParam = Join(destinations, "|")
    URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=" & Escape(originsParam) & "&destinations=" _
    & Escape(destinationsParam) & "&mode=" & TravelMode & "&key=" & APIkey

    With xmlDoc
        .async = False
        .Load URL
        Debug.Print .XML
        Print #n, .XML
    End With

End Sub
```

Function:

```vb
Public Function Escape(ByVal param As String) As String

    Dim i As Integer, BadChars As String

    BadChars = "%<>=&!@#$^()+{[}]|\;:'"",/?"
    For i = 1 To Len(BadChars)
        param = Replace(param, Mid(BadChars, i, 1), "%" & Hex(Asc(Mid(BadChars, i, 1))))
    Next
    param = Replace(param, " ", "+")
    Escape = param

End Function
```

Here is XML output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DistanceMatrixResponse>
    <status>OK</status>
    <origin_address>London, UK</origin_address>
    <origin_address>Manchester, UK</origin_address>
    <origin_address>Liverpool, UK</origin_address>
    <origin_address>Bristol, UK</origin_address>
    <origin_address>Bath, UK</origin_address>
    <destination_address>Cambridge, UK</destination_address>
    <destination_address>Leeds, UK</destination_address>
    <destination_address>Cambridge, UK</destination_address>
    <destination_address>Norwich, UK</destination_address>
    <destination_address>Brighton, UK</destination_address>
    <row>
        <element>
            <status>OK</status>
            <duration>
                <value>5420</value>
                <text>1 hour 30 mins</text>
            </duration>
            <distance>
                <value>103024</value>
                <text>103 km</text>
            </distance>
        </element>
        <element>
            <status>OK</status>
            <duration>
                <value>13268</value>
                <text>3 hours 41 mins</text>
            </duration>
            <distance>
                <value>313516</value>
                <text>314 km</text>
            </distance>
        </element>
        <element>
            <status>OK</status>
            <duration>
                <value>5420</value>
                <text>1 hour 30 mins</text>
            </duration>
            <distance>
                <value>103024</value>
                <text>103 km</text>
            </distance>
        </element>
        <element>
            <status>OK</status>
            <duration>
                <value>8674</value>
                <text>2 hours 25 mins</text>
            </duration>
            <distance>
                <value>189805</value>
                <text>190 km</text>
            </distance>
        </element>
        <element>
            <status>OK</status>
            <duration>
                <value>6696</value>
                <text>1 hour 52 mins</text>
            </duration>
            <distance>
                <value>103629</value>
                <text>104 km</text>
            </distance>
        </element>
    </row>
    <row>
        <element>
            <status>OK</status>
            <duration>
                <value>12617</value>
                <text>3 hours 30 mins</text>
            </duration>
            <distance>
                <value>301588</value>
                <text>302 km</text>
            </distance>
        </element>
        <element>
            <status>OK</status>
            <duration>
                <value>3723</value>
                <text>1 hour 2 mins</text>
            </duration>
            <distance>
                <value>71765</value>
                <text>71.8 km</text>
            </distance>
        </element>
        <element>
            <status>OK</status>
            <duration>
                <value>12617</value>
                <text>3 hours 30 mins</text>
            </duration>
            <distance>
                <value>301588</value>
                <text>302 km</text>
            </distance>
        </element>
        <element>
            <status>OK</status>
            <duration>
                <value>15640</value>
                <text>4 hours 21 mins</text>
            </duration>
            <distance>
                <value>336098</value>
                <text>336 km</text>
            </distance>
        </element>
        <element>
            <status>OK</status>
            <duration>
                <value>16712</value>
                <text>4 hours 39 mins</text>
            </duration>
            <distance>
                <value>417143</value>
                <text>417 km</text>
            </distance>
        </element>
    </row>
    <row>
        <element>
            <status>OK</status>
            <duration>
                <value>13457</value>
                <text>3 hours 44 mins</text>
            </duration>
            <distance>
                <value>312942</value>
                <text>313 km</text>
            </distance>
        </element>
        <element>
            <status>OK</status>
            <duration>
                <value>5458</value>
                <text>1 hour 31 mins</text>
            </duration>
            <distance>
                <value>117472</value>
                <text>117 km</text>
            </distance>
        </element>
        <element>
            <status>OK</status>
            <duration>
                <value>13457</value>
                <text>3 hours 44 mins</text>
            </duration>
            <distance>
                <value>312942</value>
                <text>313 km</text>
            </distance>
        </element>
        <element>
            <status>OK</status>
            <duration>
                <value>17245</value>
                <text>4 hours 47 mins</text>
            </duration>
            <distance>
                <value>409544</value>
                <text>410 km</text>
            </distance>
        </element>
        <element>
            <status>OK</status>
            <duration>
                <value>17253</value>
                <text>4 hours 48 mins</text>
            </duration>
            <distance>
                <value>437125</value>
                <text>437 km</text>
            </distance>
        </element>
    </row>
    <row>
        <element>
            <status>OK</status>
            <duration>
                <value>11371</value>
                <text>3 hours 10 mins</text>
            </duration>
            <distance>
                <value>269123</value>
                <text>269 km</text>
            </distance>
        </element>
        <element>
            <status>OK</status>
            <duration>
                <value>12344</value>
                <text>3 hours 26 mins</text>
            </duration>
            <distance>
                <value>333320</value>
                <text>333 km</text>
            </distance>
        </element>
        <element>
            <status>OK</status>
            <duration>
                <value>11344</value>
                <text>3 hours 9 mins</text>
            </duration>
            <distance>
                <value>272045</value>
                <text>272 km</text>
            </distance>
        </element>
        <element>
            <status>OK</status>
            <duration>
                <value>14866</value>
                <text>4 hours 8 mins</text>
            </duration>
            <distance>
                <value>386263</value>
                <text>386 km</text>
            </distance>
        </element>
        <element>
            <status>OK</status>
            <duration>
                <value>10533</value>
                <text>2 hours 56 mins</text>
            </duration>
            <distance>
                <value>254730</value>
                <text>255 km</text>
            </distance>
        </element>
    </row>
    <row>
        <element>
            <status>OK</status>
            <duration>
                <value>11688</value>
                <text>3 hours 15 mins</text>
            </duration>
            <distance>
                <value>264172</value>
                <text>264 km</text>
            </distance>
        </element>
        <element>
            <status>OK</status>
            <duration>
                <value>13467</value>
                <text>3 hours 44 mins</text>
            </duration>
            <distance>
                <value>352919</value>
                <text>353 km</text>
            </distance>
        </element>
        <element>
            <status>OK</status>
            <duration>
                <value>11662</value>
                <text>3 hours 14 mins</text>
            </duration>
            <distance>
                <value>267094</value>
                <text>267 km</text>
            </distance>
        </element>
        <element>
            <status>OK</status>
            <duration>
                <value>15183</value>
                <text>4 hours 13 mins</text>
            </duration>
            <distance>
                <value>381312</value>
                <text>381 km</text>
            </distance>
        </element>
        <element>
            <status>OK</status>
            <duration>
                <value>10850</value>
                <text>3 hours 1 min</text>
            </duration>
            <distance>
                <value>249779</value>
                <text>250 km</text>
            </distance>
        </element>
    </row>
</DistanceMatrixResponse>
```

Comment: what does the XML look like when imported to excel?

Comment: 25 xml responses because 5 x 5 = 25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special-purpose language designed to tranform XML files into end-use formats including other XML files, HTML files, even text files. Here, XSLT can transform your *DistanceMatrixResult* structure into a CSV format with needed headers and data rows to be imported into an Excel spreadsheet. The Office library, MSXML (which you already use), can run XSLT 1.0 scripts.

And the reason you receive 25 *element* requests is each pair-wise matching of the 5 origination and 5 destination sites (`5*5`). Each *row* is a pair match (i.e., London, UK to all five destinations). Map these pairing accordingly in XSLT. By the way, forget parsing the text, use the values instead where *duration* is measured in seconds and *distance* in meters. Even have XSLT run the math conversion into decimal hours and decimal km!

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, special .xml file, to be read in VBA)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="DistanceMatrixResponse">
    <xsl:text>origin_address,destination_address,duration,distance&#xa;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="row"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row">
      <xsl:variable name="row_pos"><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></xsl:variable>

      <xsl:for-each select="element">
        <xsl:variable name="elem_pos"><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="quot">&quot;</xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($quot, ancestor::DistanceMatrixResponse/origin_address[position() = $row_pos], $quot, ',',
                                     $quot, ancestor::DistanceMatrixResponse/destination_address[position() = $elem_pos], $quot, ',', 
                                     format-number(duration/value div 3600, '##.####'), ',', 
                                     format-number(distance/value div 100, '##.####'))"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Online Demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq6Z/1)

**VBA**

```vb
Public Sub RunXSLTtoCSV()
    Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument30, xslDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument30
    Dim txtOutput As String, csvfile As String

    ' LOAD XML AND XSL
    xmlDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\Google\Maps\API\Response.xml"
    xmlDoc.async = False
    xslDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\XSLT\Script.xsl"
    xslDoc.async = False

    ' TRANSFORM TO TEXT
    txtOutput = xmlDoc.transformNode(xslDoc)

    ' SAVE TO CSV (TO IMPORT INTO EXCEL)
    csvfile = "C:\Path\To\CSV\File.csv"
    Open csvfile For Output As #1
        Print #1, txtOutput
    Close #1

    Set xslDoc = Nothing
    Set xmlDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Output**

[image: CSV Output]